# Construction measurement software

Tags: drawing

I regularly make measurements of tables, walls, rooms, construction projects, et cetera. I'd like to put these measurement in an app, so they look nicer and I can share them.

Most apps I see are way to complicated for what I need. The core functionality I need is drawing 2D shapes and placing measurement data in that. The drawing should be reasonably proportional.

I'm really looking for basic functionality. With "looking nice" i mean a computer-aided drawing. With "share" I mean: export to png as bare minimum.

I googled for around an hour and tried a dozen or so apps.

Comment: Please be more specific about your needs. What does "look nicer" mean exactly? What does "share them" mean, printing, PDFs, or what? What dozen apps? Exactly what about those apps did or did not meet your needs. Stack Exchange is designed for *specific* laser-focused questions, not wide-open conversations.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Inkscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape).

- "way to complicated": Inkscape has some very fancy features, but its interface is intuitive enough that you won't need to learn about those if you don't need them.
- "drawing 2D shapes": The main feature of Inkscape.
- "computer-aided drawing": Check; it's a drawing program.
- "placing measurement data in that": You can do this with the text tool.
- "The drawing should be reasonably proportional": Inkscape has various grid and alignment tools that make this easy.
- "export to png": Check.

It's free software and runs on Unix-likes (including Mac OS X) and Windows.